# Arma 3 Death Valley, Finding and Deploying UAv

Tags: pc, technical-issues, arma-3

I am playing the first part of the Arma 3 single player campaign, "Survive" on the mission "Death Valley."  I can complete the mission up to the point when the squad begins being mortared, and the player is tasked with deploying a UAV to find the enemy mortar crew.

Every time, I can find the body with the UAV terminal on it, but I can never seem to find the UAV itself.  Using the UAV terminal does nothing other than bring up a map screen.  The UAV bag on the body has nothing in it.

I have played the mission in the past where I have found the quad-rotor, but I cannot, for the life of me, consistently remember where to find the UAV itself.  Is it on the same person where you find the UAV terminal?  Where can I find the quad-rotor, so that I can assemble it and complete that mission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there is nothing in the bag when you look, the UAV is dissasembled inside. Put the UAV backpack ON YOU. Then choose assemble UAV from action-menu. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

the uav is the bag itself.loot the bag